# Updating rows without unique key

Tags: php, mysql

I use mySQL (engine: myISAM) and php for an interface.

My aim: fill a numeric field in each row of a table by looping through the table and incrementing a variable whose value is assigned to the said field.

A simple piece of code would look like this:

```
$NumOfRows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT * FROM voc"))

$Offset = 1;

While (($Offset-1) < $NumOfRows)
{

  mysqli_query($connexion, "UPDATE voc SET id=$Offset WHERE **??rownumber??**=$Offset LIMIT 1");

  $Offset = $Offset + 1;
}
```

I have put into double question marks what one could expect to be the counterpart of the *offset* argument of the mySQL SELECT command. Such an argument does not exist for UPDATE, of course.

My question is: How do you traverse a table and manipulate individual rows?

**CONSTRAINT**: there is no unique key in the table which allows to use the WHERE parameter (such as: `WHERE id=[any value]`).

COMMENT: Being a seasoned user of 4thDimension, I am more than baffled: in 4thDimension, you can loop through a table starting (for instance) from the first row to the last row with appropriate commands and record changes to any row by a simple command. As a newcomer to mySQL, I can only suspect there MUST be some efficient workaround.

Comment: not really sure what you are wanting to do. best i can guess is update every named row by a fixed value?

Comment: If you don't want to follow Martijn Pieters suggestion on creating primary keys, then your only option is loading all table contents in a map, do your updating, then drop the table and insert everything again

Comment: @MartijnPieters Of course you can, this is a perfectly valid SQL table: `CREATE TABLE test (nonunique int);` where you can insert any number of duplicate values. You then have a table, where you cannot _uniquely_ identify every row by _any_ combination of columns.

Comment: @lanzz: Yet the database tracks internally which row is which. Unfortunately, I just discovered that MySQL does not expose this identifier. So, in MySQL, it's a rather silly idea to not include some unique identifier in your table definition.

Comment: Why do you assume that MySQL distinguishes internally between such rows? What operation on them would require the engine to have an internal identifier, besides the implicit identification by the actual storage location of each row?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their involvement. @lanzz: MySQL has to be able to distinguish between 'rows' for these must be C-analogous 'Struct' type and as such are records in a file (a 'table'). Any retrieval algorithm uses a record address (usually a long- or extended-type unsigned integer) that can be inserted in a list or a tree, and this just sinks in with Martijn Pieters' assertion as to 'which row is which'.

Comment: Very strange… there is that 'msql_data_seek' php function that seems to fit but appears to have no msqli equivalent. I suppose (remember I am a novice with MySQL) that msql_ functions are part of a C-connector library and it makes sense, for pointers or handles are core C programming. Sorry for being a bit heavy, perhaps, but I'm trying to really figure out how this thing works.

Comment: The storage address of a record is not reliable as a unique identifier, as the record might need to be reallocated in a different position when its contents change. I haven't heard of a DBMS that exposes record storage location as an identifier for the record; some DBMS have implicit primary keys which might be exposed, but not record address. MySQL has no such implicit primary keys, as far as I know. `mysql_data_seek()` is used to move the "current row" pointer in an existing result, but it does not correspond in any way to actual records in the database, only to rows in a result set.

Comment: @lanzz — Sounds quite clear. Actually, your remark is more detailed than my initial comment, although we do view it the same way: what you call an 'existing' result must be a linked list and mysql_data_seek has to be a function that returns a pointer to a list node. Thanks again for your assistance. I suspect we might get in touch again later on. Cheers.

Comment: I mean "existing result" in the sense of a result set generated as a response to a query. As you can see from the [PHP docs](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php), `mysql_data_seek` cannot be used with `mysql_unbuffered_query()`, i.e. it _requires_ that the client (PHP) has already retrieved _the entire_ result set, and that "data seeking" happens entirely in the client, within the buffered result received from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you appear to be trying by using [custom variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html):

```
SET @seq := 0;
UPDATE voc SET id = @seq := @seq + 1;
```

(Note that in contrast to your approach, you don't need to select anything in advance, and you don't need to update each row in a separate query, but all rows are processed in a single `UPDATE`; you need to execute the `SET` as a separate query from the `UPDATE`)

Comment: Thank you, lanzz. What is that ':=' assignment syntax? It looks like Pascal… Does it exist in MySQL (as well as '=')? If Yes, how is it interfaced by php and, more generally, is the SET command interfaced by the php ini_set function?

Comment: Gotcha! I used this query:  $r= mysqli_query ($connexion, "SET @increment:=0");

Comment: Gotcha! I used this query:  $r= mysqli_query ($connexion, "SET @increment:=0"); And it works. I have sorted out that ":=" thing. I find this very disturbing: id=@seq:=seq+1 for it means there are TWO assignment operators —one for fields and one for variables. It doesn't make sense to me but I shall bear it in mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: Custom variable assignment is described in the link I have already provided in my answer. Assignment in many languages is a valid expression that evaluates to the value being assigned, thus you have very common idioms like `var1 = var2 = var2 = 0`. You cannot use it that way in SQL, as `=` is actually a comparison operator and its assignment usage in `UPDATE` is a special case.

Comment: Why… a clear syntactical system should not allow 'special' cases (equivocal), just as mathematics have only one meaning attached to one symbol (univocal). Be that as it may, it's leave it or love it, I suppose.

Comment: It is a special case in the sense that the grammar is defined as `UPDATE <table> SET <column> = <expression> ...`, i.e. `=` in the _query grammar_ denotes assignment, but in the _expression grammar_ it is a comparison operator.